# Spinner items inside expendable list view are black

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I have an ExpendableListView that include two custom items.
In one item I have spinner view,
This is my code:
1. Here you can see the first custom xml item insertion

```
LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
        inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View search_details = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.search_details, null);
        dateCheckBox= (CheckBox) search_details.findViewById(R.id.dateCheckBox);
        locationCheckBox= (CheckBox) search_details.findViewById(R.id.locationCheckBox);
        depCheckBox= (CheckBox) search_details.findViewById(R.id.depCheckBox);
        urgencyCheckBox= (CheckBox) search_details.findViewById(R.id.urgencyCheckBox);

        departmentSpinner= (Spinner) search_details.findViewById(R.id.departmentSpinner);
        depTextView= (TextView) search_details.findViewById(R.id.depTextView);
        depCheckBox= (CheckBox) search_details.findViewById(R.id.depCheckBox);
        if(admin.getRole().description.toUpperCase().equals(ADMINISTRATOR))
        {
            departmentSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            depTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            depCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        mLinearScrollFirst.addView(search_details);     
        mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
```

2. Here you can see the item XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="430dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="לפי תאריך"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/dateCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/focused_search_contactings_activity_LinearLayout12_height"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="3.5" 
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.6" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/date_end_EditText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.40"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:inputType="date" 
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/date_end_button"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.40"
                    android:background="@drawable/dateicon" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/between" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1.6"
               >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/date_start_EditText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.39"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:inputType="date" 
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp">

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/date_start_button"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.39"
                    android:background="@drawable/dateicon" />
            </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="לפי מיקום"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/locationCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                style="@style/TitelTheme"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:text="@string/address" >
                            </TextView>



                            <Spinner
                                android:id="@+id/GetStreetsSpinner"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/gray_button_address_arrow"/>


     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="לפי דחיפות"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/urgencyCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/depTextView"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="לפי מחלקה"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/depCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

     <Spinner
          android:visibility="invisible"
          android:id="@+id/departmentSpinner"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:layout_gravity="right" 
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
          android:paddingRight="30dp"
          android:background="@drawable/gray_button_address_arrow"/> 

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/save_user_details_message_activity_ok_btn_height"
                android:background="@drawable/green_button"
                android:text="@string/search_button_txt"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
               />



</LinearLayout>
```

All spinners are black when I open them, I tried to remove the background attribute but its still black when I open them.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: can you try to add this attribute android:popupBackground="YOUR_COLOR"

Comment: Thank you! working for me :) can you add your answer to the answers? I want to upvote it and mark! its verey good answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to add this attribute

```
android:popupBackground="ENTER_YOUR_COLOR_HERE"
```